# Can a "sum of two squares" solution be the average of two other solutions?

Tags: factoring

If $n = a^2 + b^2$ and $n$ has more than two unique solutions for $a$ and $b$ (where unique means that $a$ and $b$ are unsigned and unordered), then is it possible, impossible, or unknown whether one solution can be the average of two other solutions? For example, given three solutions:

$n = j^2 + k^2$

$n = s^2 + t^2$

$n = x^2 + y^2$

Can $j^2$ and $k^2$ can be the average of the other two solutions? Is this possible:

$j^2 = \frac{s^2 + x^2}{2}$

$k^2 = \frac{t^2 + y^2}{2}$

Where might I learn more? I ask because I've been playing with the "3x3 magic square of squares" problem and this seems to be a core question. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: The (complete) solutions to $ a^2 + b^2 = 2c^2$ are $ a= s^2 + 2st - t^2, b = -s^2 + 2st + t^2, c = s^2 + t^2$. Use that to get new conditions, solve that system, and hence find non-trivial solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observations towards a solution

- $ s^2 + x^2 = 2j^2$ has parametrized solutions for integers $a, b, k$ of
  $$ s = k(a^2 + 2ab -b^2), x =k( -a^2 + 2ab + b^2), j = k(a^2 + b^2).$$

  - This can be algebraically verified.
  - In the event that the values are negative, just take the absolute value.
  - Note: This is a complete classification, but we don't require this fact. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3683938) for more details.
- Likewise, $ t = c^2 + 2cd - d^2,  y = -c^2 + 2cd + d^2$.
- Now, since $s^2 + t^2 = x^2 + y^2$, expanding the expression and simplifying yields
  $$ ab(a^2 - b^2) = cd(d^2 - c^2).$$
- This has solutions like $ a = 6, b = 1,  c = 2, d = 5$.

  - There are also other solution sets, like $ a = 7, b = 3, c = 7, d = 8$. (Obtained by setting $ a = c$ as a simplification.)
  - I don't know how to get a complete classification of the solutions. These were mainly found by trial and error.
- This yields $n = 47^2 + 1^2 = 37^2 + 29^2 = 23^2 + 41^2, 47^2 + 23^2 = 2\times 37^2, 1^2 + 41^2 = 2 \times 29^2 $.

Comment: Neat! Now I just need to extrapolate the above to solve:
$h = \frac{t^2+x^2}{2}$

$i = \frac{s^2+y^2}{2}$
And then redesign my GPU search. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Thanks again for helping. I'm trying to verify this empirically and I run into a snag. If $j = 325$ then $2j^2$ has eight solutions that are the sum of squares but only three are derivable as described above from the sum of squares that equal 325 itself. What am I missing?

Comment: @DavidZarzycki Can you state which ones you can't derive? $\quad$ I might be quoting the complete classification wrongly -  Maybe we'd need to allow for negative $a, b$.

Comment: For example via WolframAlpha: `PowersRepresentations[2*325^2,2,2]` has eight solutions but `PowersRepresentations[325,2,2]` has three solutions.

Personally speaking the missing solutions don't seem applicable to the magic square puzzle I'm playing with so I'm beyond thrilled with the performance gains the above trick yielded in my code. Thanks!

I don't want some future internet person to find this post and think that the above trick finds all solutions if that's important.

Comment: Ah, these are the "primitive solutions", so they will have to be scaled by a factor of $k$. I've updated the writeup to reflect this. $\quad$ Explicitly, With $ k = 1$, and we get the mapping of solutions $\{ 1, 18 \} \Rightarrow \{ 287, 359\} $, $\{  6, 17\} \Rightarrow \{ 49, 457 \}$, $ \{ 10, 15\} \Rightarrow \{ 175, 425\}$.  For $k = 5$, we get the mapping of solutions $ \{ 1, 8 \} \Rightarrow  \{235, 395 \}    $ , $ \{ 4, 7 \}  \Rightarrow \{ 115, 445 \}$. With $k = 13, $ $\{ 3, 4 \} \Rightarrow \{ 221, 403\}$, $\{5, 0 \} \Rightarrow \{ 325, 325\}$ etc.